# Dynamically messaging vs Latency design issue

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, architecture, jms

I would like to know yours thoughts about my design from your experience.

I am designing a system having a very critical part:

I have component A,B,C(on the same JVM) which need to "speak" with each other.

I could have two ways doing so:

1. Method call way(each one holds each other instances (injection, object instance,etc..)
2. messaging way(topic/queue)

I am aware to cons of having a middle ware messing system(option-2).

BUT:

I am talking about **latency** considerations. 
I need to have those messages reached to the targets in low latency (talking about ms latency).

I would like to choose option-2(the messaging way).

By your experience how much it will affect my latency? again latency is a very huge factor in this decision.

(Programming with Java, not sure which app container yet (Spring, Jboss..)

thanks,
ray.

Comment: There are some good thought on that problem in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729208/what-solutions-exist-for-a-jvm-based-queue-that-is-larger-than-heap).

Comment: Looked at it.. couldn't find an experienced idea enough with the examples given there.

Comment: I would say  take one step at a time. Start with the injection and see if you run into a problem where you do need to look further. Then may be a pool of threads and a queue would suffice. I would look at a messaging framework only if i am producing enough messages that require a messaging system.

Comment: @javausersoma i am into messaging framework because I with my experience it's a very dynamic\easy to maintain\loose couple environment. but of course if the tradeoff is latency ill need to re-consider.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the messaging way is in-memory, within the same JVM. Then typically most latency comes from a combination of contention (use of synchronized etc), scheduling (how threads are woken up to do their jobs and so forth) and GC. Those sources of latency tend to dwarf everything else.

It is possible to write fairly light weight messaging systems that do not add much overhead. A good example of this would be [Akka](http://akka.io/), which is increasingly finding its way into low latency financial systems. It is better known in the Scala realm, but it does have a Java API.

In conclusion, a messaging system can be implemented to sub millisecond demands. However make sure that it fits your needs first. Just because you can, does not mean that you should. If you are working on a small system then dependency injection/inversion of control may be all that you need to have a good design. However if you are looking at messaging as a way to bring multiple cpu cores into the mix, or some such then I recommend taking a look at Akka. Even if only as a case study.

Comment: I should also suggest that you are best starting with a simple design, measuring it and then modifying given that feedback first. That approach tends to trump most other considerations.

Comment: even if I use Akka.. using a topic instead of method invocation.. how much it will influence latency ?

Comment: Akka message passing has around 1-2 microsecond latency: http://www.jinspired.com/site/performance-instrumentation-monitoring-of-an-efficient-runtime-akka-part-2

Comment: Akka can be integrated inside Spring? I saw it's written for Scala isnt?

Comment: Martin Thompson writes quite a bit about how to write low latency queues. Google his name, he was the guy behind the disruptor pattern at LMAX. Java executors perform at apx 3million ops per second. It is possible to get that up to at least 50m, and pushing the bounds 200m per second is not unheard of. These timings were taken from a i7 quad core mac book pro.